# Invalid patch error in Contentful CMA client

Tags: patch, contentful, contentful-management, contentful-api

I am trying to populating an empty field by using patch method in Contentful. The following piece of code works in one cloned environment but does not work in another.

```
let patchData: OpPatch[] = [
    {
        op: 'replace',
        path: '/fields/keywords',
        value: entryKeyword,
    },
];

await cmaClient.entry.patch({ entryId: entryId }, patchData, { 'X-Contentful-Version': entryVersion });
```

When I try to execute this, receiving a 'Unprocessable Entity' error:

```
UnprocessableEntity: {
  "status": 422,
  "statusText": "Unprocessable Entity",
  "message": "Could not apply patch to entry: invalid patch",
  "details": {},
  "request": {
    "url": "/spaces/xyz/environments/abc/entries/123456789",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json",
      "X-Contentful-User-Agent": "sdk contentful-management-plain.js/7.54.2;",
      "Authorization": "Bearer ...",
      "user-agent": "node.js/v14.19.2",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
      "X-Contentful-Version": 25,
      "Content-Length": 78
    },
    "method": "patch",
    "payloadData": "[{\"op\":\"replace\",\"path\":\"/fields/keywords\",\"value\":\"test keyword\"}]"
  },
  "requestId": "abcd-123456"
}
```

I have the same exact access permissions to both environments. What am I missing out on?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - turned out when the entry doesn't have the filed you're trying to patch - it will throw an error like above.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).